# Diagrammatic Representation of Classes - Is there a standard?

Tags: php, oop, representation

I'm in the process of writing php based code as an exercise in OOP (its a WP Plugin, but I don't believe that the question is WP specific, so posted here).

I've got loads of ideas and stuff floating around my head much quicker than I can type them into working code. So I'm wondering if there's a standard method for scribbling them on a sheet of paper that will represent dependencies, links, etc? Or even if anyone has any ideas that work for themselves?

Comment: Maybe search some on UML diagrams.  [Marin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/distributedComputing/standard.html) has published some on the subject and there should be plenty on the internet too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Not something I've heard of before. I'll have a look.

Comment: Take a look at [Mind maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map)

Answer (score 0):

I'll elaborate and write this as an answer.  *Unified Modeling Language (UML)* is probably the most used specification for visualizing system architectures.  It was intended to be used specifically to describe object oriented systems.  There is a [consortium](http://www.uml.org/) that maintains versioned standards.

UML is not the same thing as *Entity-Relationship Models*.  Something else you might want to look at.  Sometimes you'll see a mix of the two, some UML with maybe more 'crows feet' style notations to depict cardinality.

I consider [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/design.html) an authority on these matters and recommend his writings.  "UML Distilled: A Brief Guide to the Standard Object Modeling Language (3rd Edition)".

Another book on the subject I can recommend is "Advanced Object-Oriented Analysis and Design using UML", by James J. Odell.

There should be many tutorials on the web too.

A great free tool for modeling is [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/).  Visio of course supports UML and ERs and many others.  More can be found here: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlSketchingTools.html